# In vue.js, Can i change parent element's css only under current router?

Tags: css, vue.js

I want to change parent's style at the component.
And I do not want change CSS at other components.
Look at my code.

**App.vue**

```
<div class="page-content">
    <router-view ref="routeview"></router-view>
</div>
```

**router/index.js**

```
  routes: [
    {   path: '/home',            name: 'Home',       component: HomeView     },
    {   path: '/heroes',      name: 'Heroes',     component: HeroesView   },
  ]
```

**HomeView**

```
<style>
.page-content {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

If I put `.page-content` CSS in global CSS area like above, it changes HerosView's style too. That is not what I want.
I want to change `.page-content` background under current HomeView page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `styled` class from `router.beforeEach` hook

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(...) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('page-content')[0].classList.toggle('styled');
    }
})

<style>
.page-content.styled {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. What i used finally is 'watch' at App.vue. 
// $route (to, from){
let pc = document.getElementById('page-content').classList;
                if( to.name == 'Home'){
                    pc.add('class_A');
                    pc.remove('class_B');
                }
            }